# Checking Javascript Errors in Selenium Testing

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium

I want to be able to find javascript errors on a web page during selenium testing, I am using selenium remotewebdriver, nunit and c#.

I was reading into a technique where you embed javascript into every page to check if there are any javascript errors present, and create a message using html to show that there is an error. This way, selenium can verify if there are any errors by checking if the message exists.
But this way seems pretty tedious because you have to write the javascript code on every single page.

Can someone recommend me better way to implement this?

Comment: Why not just include a javascript file of the code on each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach that has yielded success for a number of people is to use a proxy to inject the error handling script for you. This has the added advantage that you do not have to modify the application source code directly. An example of this technique can be found at http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/09/capturing-javascript-errors-in.html